# Adding results from a loop to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF1LK.png) Can somebody please suggest some code that would allow me to find the median of some numbers in a data frame based on meeting different criteria.

I would then like to add those median values into a data frame for each i value in numlist.

The code I have so far works but is restated twice for different .loc criteria.
I'd like to add the resulting median values to the data frame without all the unnecessary steps with the list appending, if possible.

Also, when I concatenate the data frames, the i values in numlist appear in the result twice. Those i values in numlist (appended to list n) should be the value in the first column for which the different median values are added.

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  testdata= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\Data_Sample.csv'))

  numberlist= testdata.loc[:,["ML#"]]# list of ML numbers
  numlista=numberlist['ML#'].str[:5] # sliced the ML numbers
  numlist=list(set(numlista)) #leaves original sliced values only, removes duplicates

  testdata['e']=testdata["ML#"].str[:5] #added a column to the original testdata with a sliced ML# field
  y=[]; n=[]# will be making some lists to later add data to a pandas frame

  for i in numlist: # for each original sliced ML number (subs)
   a=testdata.loc[(testdata["ABC"]==1) & (testdata["Price"]>0) &(testdata["Price"]<1000000) & (testdata['e']==str(i))] #sets a to be a list of data
                                                                                                 #that meets criteria (was (testdata["ML#"].str[:5]==str(i)))
   b= np.mean(a.loc[:,["Price"]]) # found mean of the Prices of entries that met above criteria
   c=b.tolist()                        # got just the values of said means
   y.append(str(c))                    #made list for DF             
   n.append(str(i))                    #made list for DF
   df1=pd.DataFrame({'List of serial numbers': n,'1=ABC-Mean found': y}) #

  n=[]; y=[] # had to empty these to add new values

  #Second loop, building the list of median values for each i under new criteria      
  for i in numlist: # for each original sliced ML number (subs)
   a=testdata.loc[(testdata["ABC"]==2) & (testdata["Price"]>=1000000) &(testdata["Price"]<2000000) & (testdata['e']==str(i))] #sets a to be a list of data
                                                                                                 #that meets criteria (was (testdata["ML#"].str[:5]==str(i)))
   b= np.mean(a.loc[:,["Price"]]) # found mean of the Sale Prices of entries that met above criteria
   c=b.tolist()                        # got just the values of said means
   y.append(str(c))                    #made list for DF             
   n.append(str(i))                    #made list for DF
   df2=pd.DataFrame({'List of serial numbers': n,'2=ABC-Mean found': y})

  result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner') #need the means for testdata["ABC"]==2 and testdata["ABC"]==1 to appear alongside the list of original i's in list n.
```

Thank you

Comment: Mean or median? And please provide a small example which illustrates the desired result so that we can understand the question without having to read your entire program.

Comment: Long story short, I have a CSV file with the following columns: "ML#", "ABC", "Price". I'd like to find the mean for "Price" for rows where "ABC" is say equal to 1, and then do it again with "ABC" equal to something else. I'd like to see the results of the first and second run in a table. Will attach an image.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you can use the following.
`testdata['ABC_mean'] = testdata.groupby('ABC')['Price'].transform(np.mean)`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this and let you know. Much appreciated. Meanwhile I've added a link into the body illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish overall.

Comment: Oh, if you just want the collapsed form, you can just use `testdata.groupby('ABC')['Price'].mean()`. I think that's what you're after given the image you posted.

Comment: Thank you 3novak! This is what I was trying to do.